# Is there a way to make a "oscilloscope styled" double cursor delta while plotting in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was looking for more information about whether or not it was possible to make a "oscilloscope styled" double cursor delta (like the example below) while plotting with `matplotlib`?

[image: Oscilloscope example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find below the demo of the code that allowed me to reach my goal and its output graph (**warning: x and y values are equal to the to the ones where you clicked**).

To select the first cursor, simply left click on the graph, to select the second one, simply do the same, but this time, by pressing *shift* simultaneously (or change the toggle key to the one of your liking ([`KeyEvent` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.KeyEvent))).

Do not hesitate to modify the code in order to improve it so that future users may benefit from it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import numpy as np

data_y = np.random.rand(100)
data_x = np.arange(0, len(data_y), 1)
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))
plt.plot(data_x, data_y)
cursor1 = Cursor(ax, color='r', horizOn=True, vertOn=True)
cursor2 = Cursor(ax, color='g', horizOn=True, vertOn=True)
global cursor1_x
global cursor1_y
global cursor2_x
global cursor2_y
cursor1_x = 0 
cursor1_y = 0
cursor2_x = 0
cursor2_y = 0
def on_move(event):
    cursor1.active = False
    cursor2.active = False
def on_click(event):
    global cursor1_x
    global cursor1_y
    global cursor2_x
    global cursor2_y
    if event.key == "shift":  # Toggle Key
        cursor2.active = True
        cursor2_x = event.xdata
        cursor2_y = event.ydata
    else:
        cursor1.active = True
        cursor1_x = event.xdata
        cursor1_y = event.ydata
    for t in fig.texts:
        t.set_visible(False)
    if cursor1_x != 0 and cursor1_y != 0:
        fig.text(0, 0.001, "Cursor 1: ({}, {})".format(cursor1_x, cursor1_y))
    if cursor2_x != 0 and cursor2_y != 0:
        fig.text(0.33, 0.001, "Cursor 2: ({}, {})".format(cursor2_x, cursor2_y))
    if cursor1_x != 0 and cursor1_y != 0 and cursor2_x != 0 and cursor2_y != 0:
        fig.text(0.66, 0.001, "Delta: ({}, {})".format((cursor2_x-cursor1_x), (cursor2_y-cursor1_y)))
plt.connect("motion_notify_event", on_move)
plt.connect("button_press_event", on_click)
plt.show()
```

[image: demo gif]